# Color classification with k-means clustering

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to seperate some players by their jersey color. I have a model that detects and places bounding boxes on the players. Now I'd like to seperate the teams based on their jersey color. I did some research and found out that k-means clustering can be used for this purpose. However, it is mainly used for finding the dominant colors in an image. My confusion is, do I perform the clustering for each bounding box, find the dominant color and than compare these, or do I perform the clustering for all the bounding boxes together and then perform a classification step?

```
def draw_bboxes(image, detected):
    for box, label, score in zip(detected['boxes'], detected['labels'], detected['scores']):
        if label == PLAYER:
            x1, y1, x2, y2 = box
            detect_team(image, box) #how to implement this with k-means clustering?
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you are looking for is demonstrated [here](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/tutorial-colors-image-clustering-python/) already exactly the way you want. To get the dominant color via K-Means you need to do following steps

1. Separate R, G and B colors of image so that you have 3 lists of colors
2. Scale the color values
3. Apply K-Means Clustering keeping clusters count of your choice e.g. 2
4. After clustering get the cluster centers, they are your dominant colors or at least average of dominant colors
5. Decide your team on the basis of color

Comment: Thank you. However, this, as I pointed out in my question, is a means to find dominant colors in an image. I've found various examples of this. My question is do I run this clustering algorithm for each bounding box. If so, let's say for example I have 13 detected boxes, I run clustering on each of them so I get 13 dominant colors, now do I run another clustering process to cluster them into 2 colors? How would I go about this?

Comment: i would recoment you to write a classification algorithm such as svm to futher take 13 colors as input and output the team name . i mean to say run classification algorithm on the output of clustering .